# How to overwrite data from text file into hive table replacing for specific date or for specific value

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, insert-update, cloudera-cdh

I am using cloudera Distribution with Hive version "hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.14.0" i.e. hive 1.1.0 version.

Below is my hive table:

```
hive> describe test;
OK
id                      int                                         
name                    string                                      
day                     date                                        
Time taken: 0.295 seconds,
```

Data in hive table:

```
hive> select * from test;
OK
1   ABC NULL
2   BCD NULL
3   CDE NULL
4   DEF NULL
1   ABC 2018-01-31
2   BCD 2018-01-31
3   CDE 2018-02-01
4   DEF 2018-02-01
Time taken: 0.375 seconds, Fetched: 8 row(s)
```

Now below are my scenarios:

```
1.  I need to update present/today's date replacing "NULL" in first 4 records.
2. I have a text file containing update records for record 3,4 as shown below:
       3,XYZ,2018-02-01
       4,TUV,2018-02-01
```

so now I need to replace a column name in hive table for the 2018-02-01 date. If I try to override and insert into table complete table data gets deleted and only new text file data gets inserted. but I need only new records to be updated. How can we perform the same to get below output:

Output expected for above scenarios:
scenario-1:

```
1   ABC 2018-02-01
2   BCD 2018-02-01
3   CDE 2018-02-01
4   DEF 2018-02-01
1   ABC 2018-01-31
2   BCD 2018-01-31
3   CDE 2018-02-01
4   DEF 2018-02-01
```

Scenario-2:

```
1   ABC 2018-02-01
    2   BCD 2018-02-01
    3   CDE 2018-02-01
    4   DEF 2018-02-01
    1   ABC 2018-01-31
    2   BCD 2018-01-31
    3   XYZ 2018-02-01
    4   TUV 2018-02-01
```

Kindly help me on the same. Is there any alternative way to perform this.
If this can be achieved using spark and scala pls mention the same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create tableA with total four columns (With extra column - lastUpdateTime) as below.

```
 TableA:


     id     name date           lastUpdateTime
     ------------------------------------------
     1   ABC NULL           2018-02-01 11:00:00
     2   BCD NULL           2018-02-01 11:00:00
     3   CDE NULL           2018-02-01 11:00:00
     4   DEF NULL           2018-02-01 11:00:00
     1   ABC 2018-01-31     2018-02-01 11:00:00
     2   BCD 2018-01-31     2018-02-01 11:00:00 
     3   CDE 2018-02-01     2018-02-01 11:00:00
     4   DEF 2018-02-01     2018-02-01 11:00:00
```

Lets store Text file containing Updated Records as temp_TableB.

```
temp_TableB:

     id     name date           lastUpdateTime
     ------------------------------------------
     3   XYZ 2018-02-01      2018-02-01 12:00:00
     4   TUV 2018-02-01      2018-02-01 12:00:00
```

Now combine records from both tables (tableA and temp_tableB) and insert into Temp_tableC.

```
Insert into temp_TableC
        select * from TableA
        union all 
        Select * from temp_TableB;

 temp_TableC:

     id     name date           lastUpdateTime
     ------------------------------------------ 
     1   ABC NULL           2018-02-01 11:00:00
     2   BCD NULL           2018-02-01 11:00:00
     3   CDE NULL           2018-02-01 11:00:00
     4   DEF NULL           2018-02-01 11:00:00
     1   ABC 2018-01-31     2018-02-01 11:00:00
     2   BCD 2018-01-31     2018-02-01 11:00:00 
     3   CDE 2018-02-01     2018-02-01 11:00:00
     4   DEF 2018-02-01     2018-02-01 11:00:00
     3   XYZ 2018-02-01     2018-02-01 12:00:00
     4   TUV 2018-02-01     2018-02-01 12:00:00
```

Using below query select only latest records for every 'id' and 'day' and replace NULL values with today's date.

```
Select c.id,c.day, 
     case when c.date is NULL then current_date() 
     else c.date as date
     from temp_TableC  c
     join 
     (select id,day,max(lastUpdateTime) max_lastUpdateTime from  temp_TableC group by id,day) b
     c.id=b.id and c.day=b.day and  c.lastUpdateTime=b.max_lastUpdateTime;
```

Final Output:

```
 id  name   date
     ------------------
     1   ABC 2018-02-01     
     2   BCD 2018-02-01     
     3   CDE 2018-02-01     
     4   DEF 2018-02-01     
     1   ABC 2018-01-31     
     2   BCD 2018-01-31         
     3   XYZ 2018-02-01      
     4   TUV 2018-02-01
```

Answer (score 0):

1-Mount external table on your text file say tmp table.
2-Partition your destination table on day colum.
3- join both the table by using pig  and then iterate over it to obtain new record from first half of the join and rest of non updated records from second half discarding old records.
4. overite the table, so now here your whole table will not get updated only updated partitions will be updated.

Answer (score -1):

Join 2 sets on common column and while generating, check if date is NULL push current date/required value to it.